# How do I do a regex search and replace in sublime text 2?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to remove inline style from an html document in ST2.

I imagine my regex will be something like this
    style=\"*\"

If that's wrong, it doesn't matter. I'm sure I'll figure out the expression I'll need.

What I haven't been able to figure out, is how to actually use a regex to find or to find and replace text in ST2. The docs say that it can be done. But I can't find the documentation for how to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Simply open the Search+Replace function (via Ctrl-H or the menu bar) and check the first box on the left of it (the one with an '*' on it, or you can press Alt+R)

Then the search field will be used as a Regex, and you can use the found patterns using the usual $1, $2, $3 vars in the replace box

More info [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar task to perform, the regex I used in the manner that Nas62 suggested was

```
style=\"(.*?)\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Find What : style=".*" 
 Replace With : leave it as blank

Click Replace All button.