# Creating a regex expression moving strings around

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I need to find and replace a ton of code that was written and my text editor works with regex expressions but I dont know how to make them. How would I create a regex expression to do this:

from:

```
if ($q->param('wordOne[]') =~ m/wordTwo/)
```

to :

```
if (grep /wordTwo/, $q->param('wordOne[]')) { ... }
```

wordOne/Two can be any word that is where my problem is and im not sure how to format my regex for a find and then replace to my format

Comment: What editor? Their regex engines will be different. The general syntax is often `s/find(this)/replace with \1/g` or similar, but can be something like `find\(this\)` for example (Emacs)

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617961/sublime-text-regex-find-and-replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733370/how-do-i-do-a-regex-search-and-replace-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for:

```
if \(\$q->param\('([^']+)'\) =~ m/([^/]+)/\)
```

`([^']+)` *captures* the text in between `param('` and `') =~`. `([^/]+)` is similar. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more information on capturing groups.

Replace with:

```
if (grep /\2/, $q->param('\1')) { ... }
```

`\1` and `\2` are *backreferences* to the captured text.

Output:

```
if (grep /wordTwo/, $q->param('wordOne[]')) { ... }
```

Demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/pB2jM1

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(\$q->param\('.*?\[\]'\)) =~ m(/.*?/)`

Replace: `grep \2, \1`